# Ordering by several fields using Rails Helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, helper

I have this two tables:

```
room_types
+ id
+ n_adults
+ n_children

rooms
+ id
+ name
+ hotel_id
+ room_type_id
```

I want to list all my rooms ordered by n_adults ASC. However, if two rooms have the same n_adults value, I want to sort them by n_children ASC.

So far I have this:

```
<% Room.all(:conditions => ['rooms.hotel_id = ?', @hotel_id], :joins => :room_type, :order => "room_types.n_adults ASC").each do |room| %>
```

How can I accomplish that?

Thank youuu!!!

=)

Example:

```
room 1 Adults: 1 Children: 0
room 2 Adults: 1 Children: 1
room 3 Adults: 2 Children: 1
room 4 Adults: 3 Children: 0
room 5 Adults: 3 Children: 1
room 6 Adults: 3 Children: 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
:order => "room_types.n_adults ASC, room_types.n_children ASC"
```

It generates a SQL ORDER BY clause of:

```
ORDER BY room_types.n_adults ASC, room_types.n_children ASC
```

If you are using Rails 3 or above you might like to use the newer query API, e.g.:

```
Room.joins(:room_type).where('rooms.hotel_id = ?', @hotel_id).order("room_types.n_adults ASC")
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html